# tkinter import Warning

Tags: python, tkinter

While using this :

- from tkinter import *

I get 100 warning, but when I used

- from tkinter import Tk, mainloop, TOP *
- from tkinter.ttk import Button *

It simply works fine. But the problem is I cannot just write everything that I have to import

Comment: whilst wildcard imports are allowed, for clarity it is best to avoid then:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends against wildcard imports. Doing so imports a very large number of items. If you don't use all of those items, some tools will give you warnings about the ones you don't use.

Arguably, the best way to import tkinter is with `import tkinter as tk`. Then, any items you need from the tkinter library can be used by prefixing them with `tk.` (`tk.Button`, `tk.Text`, etc)